# SendArticleAsync throw an Error "Bad Request: BUTTON_URL_INVALID"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, telegram-bot

I' m writting my Telegram bot and had an issue when I send my articles from website to Telegram. Now I have 30 articles in my local DB and it works fine until 22 item. I send 5 articles of each request. On the fifth request my application is brake down.(It send 2 news and on the third it brakes down). All articles in list isn't null and has link.

**Method for sending articles:**

```
private async Task SendArticleAsync(long chatId, int offset, int count, ITelegramBotClient _client)
        {
            var articles = await _parser.MakeHtmlRequest(offset, count);
            foreach (var article in articles)
            {
                var linkButton = KeyboardGoOver("Перейти", article.Href);
                await _client.SendPhotoAsync(chatId: chatId, photo: article.Image,
                    caption: $"*{article.Title}*", parseMode: Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.ParseMode.Markdown, replyMarkup: linkButton);

            }
            await OnLoadMoreNewsAsync(chatId, offset + count, count, _client);
        }
```

*On the 22 article method SendPhotoAsync throw an error:*

> Telegram.Bot.Exceptions.ApiRequestException: 'Bad Request: BUTTON_URL_INVALID

Why I got this error? InlineKeyBoardmarkup isn't null for 22 item, but SendPhotoAsync thow an error.

Comment: check the `article` object's properties values e.g. `article.Image` and `article.Title`

Comment: yes, I checked and all property isn't null and has values.

Comment: Its not able null only. I cannot be other values as well which are not allowed by the API.

Comment: what do you mean? Which values are not allowed by API?

Comment: for example we can restrict a number greater than 100 , if you pass 1000 API will send a bad request

Comment: @viveknuna
**article.Image** = "https://autorun.by//assets/images/resources/429/medium/a1.jpg" , **article.Href** = "https://autorun.by/novosti/soligorsk/429-«vashej-devochke-ostalsya-maksimum-god».-soligorchane,-davajte-poboremsya-za-6-letnyuyu-alisu" and **article.Title** = "Вашей девочке остался максимум год». Солигорчане, давайте поборемся за 6-летнюю Алису"